# Фильтр по meta_query

Tags: php, wordpress, acf, meta, wp-query

подскажите пожалуйста решение
Есть произвольный тип записей «Игры»
Есть фильтр по количеству возможных игроков в данной игре
В самой «Игре» количество игроков указывается в виде произвольного поля ACF Checkbox
до 1 до 8 и возвращает массив соответственно
Фильтрация происходит через AJAX
https://skr.sh/sCV4aBqG37C
человек указывает кол. игроков и нужно чтобы подгружалась игра в которой указано одно из значений
https://skr.sh/sCV3DSD4zvl
ACF возвращает массив (пример того что указано в одной игре):

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 6 )
```

Вот код который прописан для функции подгрузки
подскажите пожалуйста что нужно указать в meta_query для подобной фильтрации

```
$args = [
        'post_type' => $_POST['postType'],
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    ];

    if( isset( $_POST['playerID'] )) {
        
        $playerID = $_POST['playerID'];

        if ( $playerID == 'all' ) {
            $args['meta_query'] = [[]];
        } else {
            $args['meta_query'] = [
                'relation' => 'OR',
                [
                    'key' => 'g__players',
                    'value' => $playerID,
                    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                ],
            ];
        }
    }

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: в каком виде acf хранит эти данные?

Comment: @DarthKYL возвращает массив, а хранит не знаю

Comment: можете добавить в вопрос структуру массива?

Comment: @DarthKYL обновил, не знаю насколько я понял ваш вопрос

Comment: примерно то что нужно, еще одно уточнение значение в массиве это строка или число?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так как acf хранить сериализированный массив в ячейке ваш запрос должен быть такого вида:

```
$args['meta_query'] = [
    'relation' => 'OR',
    [
        'key' => 'g__players',
        'value' => serialize( strval( $playerID ) ),
        'compare' => 'LIKE', 
    ],
];
```

Comment: понял свою ошибку, огромное вам спасибо за ответ и пояснение